# Alternative rationale for why empty set is clopen

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I know in a topology of subsets of a set $X$ we **define** $X,\emptyset$ as open.

But can’t we use the basic properties of $\emptyset$ from set theory to establish that $\emptyset$ is clopen?

Here’s my reasoning — would like to know where the flaw is:

Assume for sake of argument that we have **not** defined $\emptyset$ as open in a given topology built from subsets of $X$.

Let $S$ be the open subsets of $X$, since $\emptyset$ is a member of every set it is also a member of $S$. This implies it must be open (no need to define it). However, since $X$ is defined to be open we have it as the complement of $\emptyset$ and hence it’s closed.

Am I being circular?

Comment: $\emptyset$ is not a member of every set, it is a subset of every set. Important difference. An open set must be a member of the topology, not a subset of the topology.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you! That makes sense!

Comment: What’s with the downvotes?

Comment: A lot of people,find certain typesmmofmconfusionminmother people annoying, and think their annoyance reflects on the other person, rather than themselves. This is a fine question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A topology on a space $X$ may be defined as a subset $\tau$ (the *open* sets) of $\mathcal P(X)$ with the following properties:

- $X\in\tau$
- if $U,V\in \tau$, then $U\cap V\in\tau$
- For a family $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ indexed by an arbitrary set $I$ and with $U_i\in \tau$ for all $i\in I$, also $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i\in \tau$

Then by taking $I=\emptyset$ in the third bullet point, we conclude that $\emptyset\in\tau$.

Comment: I guess one could also replace the second bullet point with "finite intersections". Then we can also do away with saying $X \in \tau$, since $\cap_{i \in \emptyset} U_i= X$.